# JQUERY add error class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

when the textbox is empty need to add the " error " in the class attribute.

I have the below  code, but this code does not showup after form submitted. please guide me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("page loaded");
    $("#examle_frm_id input[type='submit']").click(function(){
        alert("form has hitted");
        if (jQuery("#fname").val() == ""){
            $("#fname").addClass( "error" );
        }   
    });
})
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="examle_frm_id" >
    <input type="text" class="txt-firstname" name="fname" id="fname"  />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

some more input, i added return false after " addClass  " function. i submitted the form. form is just halted and i noticed in the firebug, class " error " is added. but if i removed the " return false  ", page get load / refreshed, what ever we added in jquery those are removed from the class.

now please advise.  how add certain class dynamically based on the condition  after form submitted.

Answer (score 0):

u should stop reloading page, if (jQuery("#fname").val() == "") happened.

```
$('#examle_frm_id').submit(function (evt) {
    alert("form has hitted");
    if (jQuery("#fname").val() == ""){
        evt.preventDefault();
        window.history.back();
        $("#fname").addClass( "error" );
    }
});
```

Comment: as per my requirement, i dont want to stop the control their.